# how to add a selector to a shape?

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable, android-selector, android-designer

How to add beloved different xml file in one file.

first file is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

second file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    <stroke android:width="0dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"/>
    <corners android:radius="25px"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: sir, but when i select item in gridview i need to change background but one background is added for design  in gridview one item how can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

try this -

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/second" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_selected="true" >
    <shape>
       <solid android:color="#xxxxxx" />
       ....
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: thank you sir, but can i add alpha in state_selected items

Comment: inside <shape> balise you can use                     <solid android:color="#xxxxxx" />